# regex phone number validation with PHP

Tags: php, regex

This is another question about a previous question I had asked [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094180/ignore-entered-text-after-a-certain-length-php-jquery-search). I want user to be allowed to type US phone numbers in the following formats.

(800)-555-1212

800-555-1212

and have it only check the database for numbers 8005551212

I've seen that regex like 
`/^[\+]?([0-9]*)\s*\(?\s*([0-9]{3})?\s*\)?[\s\-\.]*([0-9]{3})[\s\-\.]*([0-9]{4})[a-zA-Z\s\,\.]*[x\#]*[a-zA-Z\.\s]*([\d]*)/`

may work but I'm not certain how to implement it into the code from the link I provided

I'm new to php and know nothing about regex. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Two things I will never bother validating by format, emails and phone numbers. If it's imperative that the user be contactable by phone, they'll get their number right

Comment: There are many answers.Check these links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357675/validating-us-phone-number-with-php-regex

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705507/php-validation-of-us-phone-numbers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: why this question is tagged with mysql and mysqli?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I tagged it with mysql and mysqli because it was part of a project that uses mysql I posted the link in the question.

Comment: @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro But it hasn't anything to do with the question. Keep in mind, that those tags are for the context of the question.

Comment: Well if it would be for the movie tickets project you'd tag it with 'tickets' and 'movie'?

Answer (score 11):

This function validate a phone number, return true if it validate and false if invalid. This function very simple i was wrote to.

```
    /**
     * @param $number
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    function validatePhoneNumber($number) {
        $formats = [
            '###-###-####', '####-###-###',
            '(###) ###-###', '####-####-####',
            '##-###-####-####', '####-####', '###-###-###',
            '#####-###-###', '##########', '#########',
            '# ### #####', '#-### #####'
        ];

        return in_array(
            trim(preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '#', $number)),
            $formats
        );
    }
```

Comment: Be careful. It is not universal validator. It does not handle variants starting with `00` or `+` sign.

Comment: @mikep why you just not add "00 XXX" or "+ XX" ?

Comment: @DonatasNavidonskis because of you already have 12 items in array and to support `+` and `00` variants I should add 2*12 new items = together 36 items which is not so handy.

Comment: @mikep yeah, but this was one of the simple solutions, if you have more complex situation, sure this method is not fit for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

if javascript is ok can go with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function matchClick() {
  var re = new RegExp("Your regex here");
  if (document.formname.phone.value.match(re)) {
     alert("Ok");
     return true;
  } else {
     alert("Not ok");
     return false;
  }
} 
</script>
```

call this function onsubmit of form or onblur of textbox

If you have doubt about your regex you can validate it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern

**`\(?\d{3,3}\)?-\d{3,3}-\d{4,4}`**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $t='/\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}/';
    $arr=preg_match($t,'(800)-555-1212',$mat);
    $arr=preg_match($t,'800-555-1212',$mat);
    print_r($mat);
?>
```

Tested [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

Comment: Works but would need to be $arr=preg_match($t,'8005551212',$mat); not with dashes I'm going to going with @Donatas Navidonskis approach.

Answer (score 0):

Re: Rohan Kumar's solution

```
<?php
$t='/\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}/';
$arr=preg_match($t,'(800)-555-1212',$mat);
$arr=preg_match($t,'800-555-1212',$mat);
print_r($mat);
?>
```

It *does* address the issue of fake phone numbers such as 800-123-2222. Real phone numbers have a first digit of at least "2". While the other solutions do the format correctly, they don't address the issue of people putting in phone numbers like 800-000-1234, which would be correct in the other solutions provided.