# Validate phone number in php

Tags: php, regex

I am making a phone number validator and all numbers should start with `168` and then followed by 9 digits `123456789`.In total the phone number should only have 12 digits.

I have tried this

```
$phoneNumber = '168921500789';
    if( preg_match( "/^\168[0-9]{9}$/", $phoneNumber ) ){
  echo "Valid number";
} else {
  echo "Invalid number";
}
```

When i run the script,the number is not valid.How can i make the script take only 12 digits that must start with 168?.

Comment: I'm not sure about phone number validation. You can test wether it matches a pattern but this does not prevent from entering a wrong number anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your RegEx is wrong, there's an useless backslash before the `1`. Correct:

```
/^168[0-9]{9}$/
```

Full code:

```
$phoneNumber = '168921500789';
if( preg_match( "/^168[0-9]{9}$/", $phoneNumber ) ){
  echo "Valid number";
} else {
  echo "Invalid number";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You had to remove 1 slash:

```
$phoneNumber = '168921500789';
    if( preg_match( "/^168[0-9]{9}$/", $phoneNumber ) ){
  echo "Valid number";
} else {
  echo "Invalid number";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we using like this, with referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119817/regex-phone-number-validation-with-php)

```
public function validatePhoneNumber($number){
 $formats = array(
    '###-###-####', '####-###-###',
    '(###) ###-###','####-####-####',
    '##-###-####-####','####-####','###-###-###',
    '#####-###-###', '##########', '#########',
    '# ### #####', '#-### #####'
 );

 $format = trim(preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '#', $number));
 return (in_array($format, $formats)) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Be careful. It is not universal validator. It does not handle variants starting with `00` or `+` sign.